# How to run x86_64 or x86 image on Android Studio emulator in a M1 Mac?

Tags: android-studio, x86, android-emulator, x86-64, apple-m1

I'm trying to set up an x86 image on android studio in my M1 mac. Once set up, on starting the emulator it stops with the message

```
The emulator process for [device_name] has terminated.
```

Is there a way to get this working on M1 mac?